# Show submit button dynamically when email is valid

Tags: jquery

I'm sure this should be easy, but I can't get it working.

html

```
<label for="email">Enter email for updates:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="your@email.com" />
<button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('button').hide();

  $('input').keyup(function() {
    if( !validateEmail(email) ){ 
      $('button').show();
    }
  };

  function validateEmail(email) {
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    return emailReg.test( email );
  }

});
```

I'm not looking for it to be the best email validation, rather just a simple way to show users when form looks right.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Loosen up your regex. An email could be rick@capital.gov.tx or leonardo@davinci.museum. Probably another bit of `[\w-\.]+` after the @ would be find.

Comment: Why are you showing the button when the email is invalid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

5 problems :

1. a syntax error (you should have a look at your [console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) when something doesn't work)
2. you don't make the button disappear when the input isn't valid anymore
3. you don't really test the input (thanks Eli)
4. you don't check the "email" isn't empty
5. some valid email are refused by your regex (try `"valid email"@example.com`)

My proposal for the first four problems :

```
  $('button').hide();
  $('input').keyup(function() {
    if( validateEmail($(this).val()) ){ 
      $('button').show();
    } else {
      $('button').hide();
    }
  });

  function validateEmail(email) {
    if (!email) return false;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    return emailReg.test( email );
  }
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ipawiy/1/)

For the last problem, I'd suggest you to read [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Your Complex Regex](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/).

Comment: This isn't it, though.  The variable `email` isn't set anywhere.  So his call to `validateEmail` won't work.  `validateEmail($('#email').val())` then we're talking!  Feel free to edit your answer to include this change.  If not I'll submit another answer for reference.

Comment: There is still one slight snag to fix. This event is bound to all input elements and you are passing the value of the input raising the event. If you started typing in another input that wasn't expecting an email, the submit button would be removed. The even should only be bound to `$('#email')` not `$('input')`.

Answer (score 3):

An assist to what dystroy said, there is a syntax error. But additionally, you're not setting your `email` variable when calling `validateEmail`.  I also made the core more specific, per Steve's comments.  Here's the updated code.

```
$('#email').keyup(function() {
    var email = $(this).val();

    if(validateEmail(email) ){ 
      $('button[type="submit"]').show();
    }
    else {
      $('button[type="submit"]').hide();
    }

  });
```

Comment: The validateEmail method returns true when the email is valid, so your logic is reversed. Also, why would you validate when text is entered into other input fields?

Comment: I simply modified what was there, but I agree with you Steve.  I'll modify the answer to be more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dystroy, Eli Gassert & danronmoon. Loads of different errors here that you guys pointed out. For future reference this is the code from your different fixes that now works for me:

```
$('button').hide();

$('input').keyup(function() {
    var email = $('#email').val();

    if( validateEmail(email)){ 
        $('button').show();
    } else {
        $('button').hide();
    }
});

function validateEmail(email) {
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    return emailReg.test(email);
}
```